# Haskell. Lifting monad Error and local function

Tags: haskell

```
    data InterpreterM a = ExeInterpreter a | PropInterpreter a

    newtype InterpreterMT m a = InterpreterMT { runInterpreterMT :: m (InterpreterM a) }

    type Interpreter = InterpreterMT (StateT Int (ReaderT Int (ErrorT String IO)))
    data Stmts = Statements Stmt Stmts | EmptyStmts


  instance (Monad m) => Monad (InterpreterMT m) where
        return x = InterpreterMT $ return (ExeInterpreter x)
        x >>= f = InterpreterMT $ do
            m <- runInterpreterMT x 
            case m of
                (ExeInterpreter a) -> runInterpreterMT (f a)
    interpreter :: Stmts -> Interpreter ()
    interpreter EmptyStmts = return () 
    interpreter (Statements s stmts) = lift $ local (\x -> x) (interpreter stmts)





instance MonadTrans InterpreterMT where
    lift m = InterpreterMT $ do
        x <- m
        return $ ExeInterpreter x
```

Compiler gives me erorr in last line:

```
  Couldn't match type `InterpreterMT
                           (StateT Int (ReaderT Int (ErrorT String IO)))'
                  with `StateT Int (ReaderT Int (ErrorT String IO))'
    Expected type: Interpreter ()
      Actual type: InterpreterMT
                     (InterpreterMT (StateT Int (ReaderT Int (ErrorT String IO)))) ()
    In the expression: lift $ local (\ x -> x) (interpreter stmts)
    In an equation for `interpreter':
        interpreter (Statements s stmts)
          = lift $ local (\ x -> x) (interpreter stmts)
```

How to repair it and why it is an error?

Comment: Looks like you have `InterpreterMT` wrapping `InterpreterMT`, wouldn't you just need to unwrap the result of `interpreter stmts` using `runInterpreterMT` before passing it to `local id`?

Comment: Well, you need to provide `Functor` and `Applicative` instances for `InterpreterM` and `InterpreterMT`, if these are both supposed to be Monads this is a requirement anyway, but your last line just needs to be `InterpreterMT $ local (\x -> x) $ runInterpreterMT $ interpreter stmts`.  What you appear to be wanting to do looks awfully similar to Free monads, by the way.

Comment: Why do you do it in such way? Why dont you use a `lift`?

Comment: Because you haven't made `InterpreterMT` an instance of `MonadTrans` either, and `lift` returns a value of a type that has to implement `MonadTrans`.

Comment: @bheklilr I have made `MonadTrans` instance indeed, but I didn't attach this code. My fault. But, there is also problem when I use `lift` as in my first post. I edited my first post.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, two problems.

First, `lift` has the following signature:

```
lift :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => m a -> t m a
```

So you have to supply non-transformed monadic action to lift. In other words, you can't use `InterpreterMT` in an argument to `lift`.

So you would need to unwrap it:

```
lift $ local id $ runInterpreterMT $ interpreter stmts
```

But now your return types don't make sense: `runInterpreterMT $ ...` has type

```
StateT Int (ReaderT Int (ErrorT String IO)) (InterpreterM ())
```

or, shortening transformer stack to `M`,

```
M (InterpreterM ())
```

while `interpreter` returns `Interpreter ()`, which is

```
InterpreterMT (StateT Int (ReaderT Int (ErrorT String IO))) ()
```

or, shortening transformer stack,

```
InterpreterMT M ()
```

going back to type of `lift`, `m a -> t m a` becomes `M (InterpreterM ()) -> InterpreterMT M (InterpreterM ())`. `(InterpreterM ())` is *not* `()`.

The root of the problem? Your `InterpreterMT` is not actually a monad transformer, since it doesn't really transform the monad. It transforms the value.

Easy fix? Provided that you can figure out a reasonable `Monad` instance for `InterpreterMT` (one you provided is doubtful), you can define a `MonadReader` instance for `InterpreterMT`:

```
instance MonadReader r m => MonadReader r (InterpreterMT m) where
  local f = InterpreterMT . local f . runInterpreterMT
  ...
```

(you'll need `UndecideableInstances` for this particular definition)

General pattern seems to be

```
inInterpreter f = InterpreterMT . f . runInterpreterMT
```

Note that this is *not* a `Functor`.

Not sure what you want to achieve here, but this whole design seems... underdeveloped. Maybe it's a good idea to go back to drawing board and figure out what exactly you want your architecture to be like.